# Unsure why my document.getElementsByClass array is only updating with the final key, value pair of my object

Tags: javascript, html, object, iteration, getelementsbyclassname

On my site, I have a button designed to change all gender pronouns where necessary. Those necessary changes are stored in this object:

```
let tenseHash = { 'struggles': 'struggle', 'has': 'have', 'needs': 'need', 'tends': 'tend' }
```

I am retrieving the necessary words from the document like so:

```
let tense = document.getElementsByClassName('tense');
```

My function to iterate through the arrays and objects to make the switch is as follows:

```
function chooseNonBinary() {

    for (let tense1 of Object.keys(tenseHash)) {

        var tense2 = tenseHash[tense1];

        for (let i = 0; i < tense.length; i++) {

            if (tense1 = tense[i].innerText) {
                tense[i].innerText = tense2;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The final product has been resulting with all the words with `class='tense'` turning into the word 'tend'. Instead, they should be changing into the same word with a different tense. For instance, 'he struggles' should become 'they struggle' (I have another working function to change he/she/they that works fine).

Thanks for any insight you might have!

Comment: Try `===` instead of `=` within `if(...`-statement

Comment: Oh my gosh. Thank you so much for catching that!